# Nuget.Core Download all Nuget-Packages Authentication failing

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-server

I want to download all nuget packages from a private nuget feed, but my authentication is failing.

```
public void DownloadPackages(string repositoryPath, string directoryPath)
{
    var repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default
        .CreateRepository(repositoryPath);

    var allPackages = repo.GetPackages();

    foreach (var package in allPackages)
    {
        var fileName = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(directoryPath, package.GetFullName()), ".nupkg");
        Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {package.GetFullName()}");
        try
        {
            using (var stream = package.GetStream())
            {

                using (var fileStream = File.Create(fileName))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error while downloading {package.GetFullName()}: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

public void InitializeCredentials(string url, string userName, string password)
{
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
    CredentialStore.Instance.Add(new Uri(url), credentials);
}
```

I initialize my Credentials like this with `InitializeCredentials`.
But it still gives me Error 401 from the server.

I saw that visual studio generated an `ApiKey` for my private nuget-feed.
How can I place my `ApiKey` into my code - I see no possibility at `var repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default .CreateRepository(repositoryPath);` for example.

So I think my problem is the missing `ApiKey`, but maybe I am using the wrong authentication `InitializeCredentials` ?

**EDIT:**
So I am sure now - that it can't be the `ApiKey` - but what am I missing?

**EDIT:**
I am calling my methods like this:

```
var helper = new PackageHelper();
helper.InitializeCredentials("User","Password");
helper.DownloadPackages("NuGetUrl", "MyLocalFolder");
```

Comment: Where are you calling InitializeCredentials?

Comment: A line bevore DownloadPackages();

Comment: Okay, so *show* that in your question. That's part of creating a [MCVE].